# SQL subqueries : how does this give output?

Tags: sql

This is my table structure

```
 CREATE TABLE branch_book_list (
   branch_name CHAR(10),
   book_ISBN CHAR (13),
   book_name CHAR(40),
   PRIMARY KEY (branch_name, book_ISBN)
   )
```

I have these rows of data in the table:

```
branch_name book_ISBN     book_name                                
----------- ------------- ---------------------------------------- 
Branch A    1-56592-756-7 Transact-SQL Cookbook                   
Branch A    1-56592-401-0 Transact-SQL Programming                
Branch A    1-56592-401-0 Transact-SQL Programming                
Branch B    1-56592-756-7 Transact-SQL Cookbook                   
Branch B    1-56592-756-7 Transact-SQL Cookbook                   
Branch B    1-56592-401-0 Transact-SQL Programming
```

When I execute this query:

```
SELECT bbl1.*, COUNT(*) DupeCount
FROM branch_book_list bbl1
WHERE bbl1.branch_name = 'Branch A'
GROUP BY bbl1.branch_name, bbl1.book_ISBN, bbl1.book_name
HAVING NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT bbl2.*, COUNT(*)
      FROM branch_book_list bbl2
      WHERE branch_name = 'Branch B'
      GROUP BY bbl2.branch_name, bbl2.book_ISBN, bbl2.book_name
      HAVING bbl1.book_ISBN = bbl2.book_ISBN
         AND bbl1.book_name = bbl2.book_name
         AND COUNT(*) = COUNT(ALL bbl1.book_ISBN))
```

OUTPUT is

```
branch_name book_ISBN     book_name                                DupeCount   
----------- ------------- ---------------------------------------- ----------- 
Branch A    1-56592-401-0 Transact-SQL Programming                 2
Branch A    1-56592-756-7 Transact-SQL Cookbook                    1
```

When I execute only the top part of the query

```
SELECT bbl1.*, COUNT(*) DupeCount
FROM branch_book_list bbl1
WHERE bbl1.branch_name = 'Branch A'
GROUP BY bbl1.branch_name, bbl1.book_ISBN, bbl1.book_name
```

My output is

```
branch_name book_ISBN   book_name                   DupeCount
Branch A    1-56592-401-0   Transact-SQL Programming    2
Branch A    1-56592-756-7   Transact-SQL Cookbook       1
```

But when the full query is executed how do I get this output

```
branch_name book_ISBN     book_name                                DupeCount   
----------- ------------- ---------------------------------------- ----------- 
Branch A    1-56592-401-0 Transact-SQL Programming                 2
Branch A    1-56592-756-7 Transact-SQL Cookbook                    1
```

Can anyone tell me how I can get above output ?

Comment: Great question, but forget wich RDBMS are you using, guess MS SQL Server

Comment: @Yaroslav:I've tagged this question under sql.

Comment: sql mean structured query language. It's a RDBMS. What are you using: MSSQL? MySQL? Orcale? etc..

Comment: Why does it matter? The SQL posted isn't using any proprietary features that I can see and the question is RDBMS agnostic. Your second and third rows violate the PK constraint though.

Comment: I guess it matters, as it matters in all the other questions that include some code. If not, then there will be several different answers, all correct, but each one will work only on one particular RDBMS. Maybe this question is not using some clause unique for one RDBMS. But then all the other similar questions that include some code, not using propietary features, no need tag for the RDBMS they are using? I think they need it

Comment: I don't see any difference between the output you show from your first query, and the desired output you specify. So that's wrong with the output from your first query?!?!

Comment: @Yaroslav - The OP isn't asking for answers containing code. They are just asking why they get the result they are getting. The answer won't be dependant on RDBMS.

Comment: @marc_s - "how do I get this output" means "how [why] do I get this output [from the first query]" I think.

Comment: @MartinSmith: hmmm... but that first query is already producing that output ... that's what's puzzling me... he seems to already get what he's looking for... I don't see a "delta" between the output from query #1 and the desired output.....

Answer (score 0):

whats your confusion ? The filter `WHERE bbl1.branch_name = 'Branch A'`
limits all three queries to only the Branch A records... 
So the Having Not exists is redundant...
 No records being examined by the having clause can have Branch B data, because the Where clause filter in the main part of the query eliminates them.

Answer (score 0):

Your NOT EXISTS subquery searches for rows in a different branch that have the same ISBN, the same name *and the same number of duplicates*. The query includes the row in the output if there's *no match* for those conditions in the other branch.

Now, the two branches have the same items, but the number of duplicates is different, that's why both Branch A items are returned, i.e. [they are *not filtered out*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/810fd/2) by the HAVING clause. But try e.g. removing one of the two `(Branch B, 1-56592-756-7)` items, and [you'll see the difference](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9588c/2) between the complete query and the reduced version.